# Передача параметров из контроллера в представление yii

Tags: yii

У меня есть модель - класс от CActiveRecord. Он сохраняет введенные данные из форм. Нужно еще получить данные из БД и предварительно их вывести. Т.е. мне нужно вывести переменную $results - результат поиска. Я вижу три пути:

1. Передать результаты поиска в представление. Правда не знаю как. Надо что-то типа:

   ```
   $this->render('index',array('model'=>$model,'results'=>$results));
   ```
2. Сделать отдельное представление и в контроллере сделать 2 рендера. Что-то типа:

   ```
   $this->render('index1',array('results'=>$results)); //вывод результатов  
   $this->render('index2',array('model'=>$model));  //вывод форм ввода
   ```
3. В контроллер добавить public-свойство $results. Как его увидеть в представлении?

Может это вообще все неправильно. Тогда как следует поступить?

Comment: Второй вариант работает. Но "чуйка" подсказывает, что это неправильно.

Comment: а первый не работает ?

Comment: Странно. Не работал (было: неизвестная переменная results), а сейчас решил еще раз проверить, ибо это самое логичное и ЗАРАБОТАЛО)) Преобразуйте коммент в ответ - помечу правильным) Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может кто зайдет и в комментах не увидит... Вот так работает:

```
$this->render('index',array('model'=>$model,'results'=>$results));
```

Comment: А передача параметров контроллера в представление возможна в Yii1, если имеются или отсуствуют GET-запросы?

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему поиск осуществляется в описанной модели. Логичным выглядит сделать результат **свойством** модели. Или результатом **метода** поиска в модели.
В обоих случаях вызов представления имеет вид:

```
$this->render('index', ['model' => $model,]);
```

Доступ в представлении в свойству:

```
<?= $model->result; ?>
```

Или к методу (если метод возвращает не объект):

```
<?= $model->searchResult(); ?>
```

Добавлять свойство в контроллер да еще и логику его заполнения и передачи- не соответствует МVС. Это компетенция (данные и безнес-логика) модели.